# Replace multiple strings in PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace multiple words in my docx-file. I used the words from the input-elements and I pass them through the 'POST'-method. I already replaced the '$bedrijfsnaam' but I want to add more str replacements. I created '$newContents2' but as I thought, it didn't work. How can I solve this? Do I have to add another 'oldContents' like 'oldContents2'?

```
$bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
$offertenummer = $_POST['offertenummer'];
$naam = $_POST['naam'];

$zip = new ZipArchive;
//This is the main document in a .docx file.
$fileToModify = 'word/document.xml';
$wordDoc = "Document.docx";
$newFile = $offertenummer . ".docx";

copy("Document.docx", $newFile);

if ($zip->open($newFile) === TRUE) {

    $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);

    $newContents = str_replace('$bedrijfsnaam', $bedrijfsnaam, $oldContents);

    $newContents2 = str_replace('$naam', $naam, $oldContents);

    $zip->deleteName($fileToModify);

    $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);


    $return =$zip->close();
    If ($return==TRUE){
        echo "Success!";
    }
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}

$newFilePath = 'offerte/' . $newFile;

$fileMoved = rename($newFile, $newFilePath);
```

Comment: `'$bedrijfsnaam'` is that literal value, dont quote variables. You can use arrays for the search and replace values, see the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: Also be careful about the dollar sign in double-quoted strings - php will try to parse the variables and replace the text with the variable (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to keep editing the same content.

```
$newContents = str_replace('$bedrijfsnaam', $bedrijfsnaam, $oldContents);
```

The result of the first replacement is in `$newContents`, so if you want to build upon that, you need to replace the second string in `$newContents` and store the result in `$newContents`, which now contains the result of both string replacements.

```
$newContents = str_replace('$naam', $naam, $newContents);
```

Edit: Better yet, you can just use arrays and do it all in one line

```
$newContent = str_replace(
    ['$bedrijfsnaam', '$naam'],
    [ $bedrijfsnaam, $naam], 
    $oldContents
);
```